# Integral of $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2+1}dx$ using Feynman integration.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, laplace-transform

Using $$I(t) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2(tx)}{x^2+1}dx$$ I want to know how to get an answer using Feynman integration and the Laplace transform of a differential equation. The correct answer is $\frac{(1-e^{-2})\pi}{4}$, but I keep getting $(1-e^{-2})\pi$, so I want to see where I have made a mistake.

Here is the method: setting $t = 1$ provides the integral in question. By repeatedly differentiating $I(t)$, you  can obtain the differential equation that $4  I'(t) = I'''(t)$. Setting $J(t) = I'(t)$, use a Laplace transform to obtain $J(t)$. Now integrate $\int_0^1 J(t)dt$,  which is equal to $I(1) - I(0)$ from the second fundamental theorem of calculus. Since $I(0) = 0$, solving for $I(1)$ yields the integral in question.

Keep in mind that I'm still in high school, so all I really know how to do is partial derivatives and Laplace transforms to solve differential equations. If something is beyond the subjects of multivariable calculus, please continue to answer the question, but know that what I am looking for is an answer through the Feynman technique and Laplace transforms.

Comment: Shouldn't the final answer depend on $t$? (I assume there is some typo).

Comment: well... the "Feynman integration" was discovered some centuries ago by [Leibniz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) :)

Comment: @Masacroso The required theorem dates back to Leibniz, but I don't think the idea of writing an integral $I$ as $\frac{dJ}{da}(a_0)$ where $J$ is some other integral with a parameter $a$ in it really went back that far.

Comment: Feynman just read the trick in a book and started to use it intensively

Comment: @Ian I have edited the question to clarify the method I used

Comment: @Masacroso  I simply called it Feynman integration as a term of generality. Not trying to diss papa Leibniz.

Comment: I guess there is a mistake in the assertion $4 I'(t)=I'''(t)$. Using Wolfram Mathematica I get $$4 I'(t)-I'''(t)=\int_0^\infty 4x\sin(2tx)\, dt$$ what diverges whenever $x\neq 0$

Comment: sorry, in my previous comment I mean $$\int_0^\infty 4x \sin(2tx)\, dx$$ what also diverges for any value of $t\neq 0$

Comment: @Masacroso this is why I am asking for a worked out solution. Some wired things happen in getting a differential equation, which would explain the disparity from wolfram

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, note that $\sin^2(tx)=\frac12(1-\cos(2tx))$.  Hence, we see that

$$I(t)=\frac\pi4-\frac12 \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(2tx)}{x^2+1}\,dx\tag1$$

Differentiating under the integral in $(1)$ can be justified by noting that the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(2tx)}{x^2+1}\,dx$ converges uniformly for $|t|\ge \delta>0$.  Proceeding reveals

$$\begin{align}
I'(t)&=\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(2tx)}{x^2+1}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{(x^2+1-1)\sin(2tx)}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(2tx)}{x}\,dx-\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(2tx)}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac\pi2 \text{sgn}(t)-\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(2tx)}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx\tag2
\end{align}$$

Similarly, we can differentiate $(2)$ to obtain

$$\begin{align}
I''(t)&=-2\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(2tx)}{x^2+1}\,dx\\\\
&=4I(t)-\pi\tag3
\end{align}$$

From $(3)$ we have $I''(t)-4I(t)=-\pi$, while from $(1)$ we see that $I(0)=0$ and from $(2)$ we see that $\lim_{t\to 0^\pm}I'(t)=\pm \frac\pi2$.  Solving this ODE with these initial conditions, we find

$$I(t)=\frac\pi4 -\frac\pi4 e^{-2|t|}$$

Comment: Thank you. I see now that my error occurred in finding the differential equation .

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

Hello felllow high school student :)

Here is the solution for $t\ge 0$. You can naturally continue it for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

\begin{align}
I'(t)&=\int_0^\infty \frac{2\sin (tx) \cos(tx) x}{1+x^2}\,dx \\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(2xt)}{1+x^2}\,dx \\
&=\int_0^\infty \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{x}{1+x^2}\right\}(s)\cdot  \mathcal{L}\left\{ \sin(2xt)\right\}(s)\,ds \qquad (1)\\
&=2t\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(s)}{4t^2+s^2}\,ds \\
&=t \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(s)}{4t^2+s^2}\,ds \\
&=t\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(s)\int_0^\infty e^{-\nu(4t^2+s^2)}\,d\nu ds \\
&=t\int_0^\infty e^{-4t^2\nu} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(s) e^{-\nu s^2}\,dsd\nu \\
&=t\int_0^\infty e^{-4t^2\nu} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\nu s^2+is}\,dsd\nu \\
&=t\int_0^\infty e^{-4t^2\nu-\frac{1}{4\nu}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\nu \left(s+\frac{i}{2\nu}\right)^2}\,dsd\nu \\
&=\sqrt{\pi}t\int_{0}^\infty e^{-4t^2\nu-\frac{1}{4\nu}}\frac{d\nu}{\sqrt{\nu}} \qquad {\lambda=2\sqrt{\nu}} \\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}t \int_{-\infty} ^\infty e^{-t^2\lambda^2-\frac{1}{\lambda^2}}\, d\lambda \\
&=t\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} e^{-2t}\int_{-\infty} ^\infty e^{-t^2\left(\lambda-\frac{1} {t\lambda}\right)^2}\, d\lambda \qquad (2)\\ 
&=t\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} e^{-2t}\int_{-\infty} ^\infty e^{-t^2\lambda^2}\, d\lambda \qquad (3) \\ 
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}t e^{-2t}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t^2}} \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2} e^{-2t}
\end{align}
Where I have used a [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) of the Laplace tranform in $(1)$, [Glasser's Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem) in $(2)$, and the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) in $(3)$.
As we know that $I(0)=0$, we can integrate this equation from $0$ to $1$ to obtain

\begin{align}
I(1)&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^1 e^{-2t}\,dt \\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\left(1-e^{-2}\right)
\end{align}

Feel free to ask if you have any questions. I know there's a lot in this answer, but I think that you can definitely learn some nice tricks from it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Quite honestly I have no idea whats going on here at the moment, but that gets me pretty excited to learn about it later. That Gaussian integral seems to pop up everywhere. Very cool solution.

Comment: I like your excitement!

Comment: @SuchetanDontha - I'm going through a bit of a Feynman + Laplace phase at the moment. Here's my recent ones (thought you may be interested)

https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:150203+[laplace-transform]