# Gaussian integral applications

Tags: calculus

Ive been researching on the gaussian integral for a while $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx$ and i’ve seen some uses for it but nothing really specific. I was wondering what are the uses and applications of the gaussian integral and where does it appear in the said applications? I found out various solutions for the integral but I haven’t been able to find a source that properly explains the applications the integral, just mostly stating a vague usage in normal distribution in normalizing the constant among various things.

Comment: Normal distributions (including CLT, approximation of Binomial and others) is a *huge* application.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2997748/integral-of-int-0-infty-frac-sin2xx21dx-using-feynman-integratio here is a cool place it popped up if you're interested